RTCPeerConnection.connectionState does not change to connected state
I have written react-native application that using RTCPeerConnection (from react-native-webrtc) that I run on my both Android phones throug USB debugging. Also I have my own local signaling server (I use a native WebSocket as transport). Everything seems written correct, but now I cannot establisch a simple connection beetween 2 peers for some reason on my phones. I noticed that peerConnection.connectionState is always new (should be transmitted to connected state). I cannot figure out why.
This is code of my react-native application (minimized for convenience):


import {Button,SafeAreaView,ScrollView,StyleSheet,Text,View} from 'react-native';
import { mediaDevices,MediaStream,RTCIceCandidate, RTCPeerConnection} from 'react-native-webrtc'
import { reconnectWebSocket, webSocket } from './socket'; //webSocket is `new WebSocket`, logic for reconnecting if state is CLOSED

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>(null);
  const peerConnection = useRef<RTCPeerConnection | null>(null);
  const [iceServers, setIceServers] = useState<Object[]>([]); 

  const [callerId, setCallerId] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)); //ID for caller
  let calleeId = useRef<number | null>(null); //ID for callee

  useEffect(() => {
    console.info(`Caller ID: ${callerId}`)
    const getAndSetIceServers = async(): Promise<Object[]> => {      
      const _iceServers = [{ url: 'stun:freestun.net:3478' }]      
      try {
        //simplicated
        setIceServers(_iceServers);  
        return Promise.resolve(IceServers);     
        }
        catch (e: any) {
          console.log(`Error while fetching TURN`);
          //some fall-back
        }      
    }
    getAndSetIceServers().then(async() =>
      await createPeerConnection()
    );
    //fired when WebSocket open
    const onOpen = async () => {
      try {
        //send to my server 'connection' event
        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "connection", data: { callerId: callerId } }));
        setCallStatus(CallStatuses.READY);
      }
      catch (e) {                  
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
    //fired when message from server
    const onMessage = async (event: WebSocketMessageEvent) => {
      let message = JSON.parse(event.data);
      switch (message.type) {
        case "candidate":
          {
            await handleCandidate(message);         
            break;
          }
        case "offer":
          {
            await handleOffer(message);
            break;
          }
        case "answer":
          {
            await handleAnswer(message);
            break;
          }
        case "icecandidate":
          {
            await hadleICECandidate(message);
            break;
          }
        case "offline":
          {
            console.log("offline handling");
            calleeId.current = null;
            break;
          }
      }
    }
    //when WebSocket error
    const onError = async (event: WebSocketErrorEvent) => {
      console.log("WebSocket error: ", event);
      setCallStatus(CallStatuses.NOT_READY);
    }
    //attach the listeners above to the WebSocket 
    webSocket.onopen = onOpen;
    webSocket.onmessage = onMessage;
    webSocket.onerror = onError;

    const handleOffer = async (offer: any) => {      
      
      calleeId.current = offer.data.callerId;
      console.log(`handleOffer calleeId: ${calleeId.current}`);
      const description = offer.data.description;
      await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(description);

      const sessionDescription = await peerConnection.current.createAnswer();
      await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
      // send answer      
      webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "answer", data: { callerId: callerId, calleeId: calleeId.current, description: sessionDescription } }));

    }

    const handleAnswer = async (answer: any) => {

      calleeId.current = answer.data.callerId;
      console.log(`handleAnswer calleeId: ${calleeId.current}`);
      const description = answer.data.description;
      await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(description);
    }

    const handleCandidate = async (candidate: any) => {
                
      calleeId.current = candidate.calleeId;
      const options = { iceRestart: false } //can be ommitted
      const offer = await peerConnection.current.createOffer(options);
      await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(offer);
      //send offer to the server
      webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "offer", data: { callerId: callerId, calleeId: calleeId.current, description: peerConnection.current.localDescription } }));
    }

    const hadleICECandidate = async (candidate: any) => {     
        const iceCandidate = candidate.data.candidate as RTCIceCandidate;
        console.log("icecandidate handling. Candidate:" + JSON.stringify(iceCandidate));
        await peerConnection.current.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
    //reconnect webSocket but here no issues..
    let reconnectTimerId = setInterval(() => { reconnectWebSocket(onOpen, onMessage, onError) }, 5000)

    return () => {
      webSocket.onopen = null;
      webSocket.onerror = null;
      webSocket.onmessage = null;
      webSocket.close(1000, callerId.toString());
      clearInterval(reconnectTimerId);
    }
  }, [])
  
  const createPeerConnection = async () => {
    
    console.debug(`Creating new RTCPeerConnection`);
    peerConnection.current = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers: iceServers})     
    peerConnection.current.addEventListener("icecandidate", iceCandidateListener); 
    console.debug(`RTCPeerConnection ${peerConnection.current._pcId} created`);
    
    const _localStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });   
    _localStream.getTracks().map((track) => peerConnection?.current?.addTrack(track))
    setLocalStream(_localStream); //keep localStream in state just for case
  }

  const iceCandidateListener = (e: any) => {
    if (e.candidate) {
      console.log(`icecandidate event: ${JSON.stringify(e)}. to calleeId=${calleeId.current}`);
        //we need to send local ICE-candidate to peer (according to ICE-trickle approach)
        webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
          type: "icecandidate", data: {
            calleeId: calleeId.current,
            candidate: e.candidate.toJSON()
          }
        }))
      console.log(`icecandidate sent from callerId ${callerId} to calleeId ${calleeId.current}`);
    }
  }
  //BUTTONS
  const goOnline = async () => {
    console.log("goOnline called");

    if (!peerConnection.current)          
      await createPeerConnection();

    webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "online", data: { callerId: callerId } }));
  }

  const goOffline = async () => {
    console.log("goOffline called");
    webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "offline", data: { callerId: callerId, calleeId: calleeId.current } }));
    calleeId.current = null;
    setCallStatus(CallStatuses.READY);
  }
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
          <View style={styles.top}>
            <Text>Caller ID: {callerId}</Text>
            <Text>Callee ID: {calleeId.current}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.bottom}>
            <Button title='ONLINE' onPress={goOnline}></Button>
            <Button title='OFFLINE' onPress={goOffline}></Button>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



On server I see all the messages and everything works fine there - so I wont provide server code. I think I missed something on the JS (TS) code, but I don't know what.
I attach the console output logs prooving that overall WebRTC flow is correct I guess.
ANDROID 1 ('Online' button clicked first):
Running "MyAppChat" with {"rootTag":51}
Caller ID: 3631
Creating new RTCPeerConnection:[]
2024-11-18T21:42:00.069Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 ctor +0ms
RTCPeerConnection 0 created
2024-11-18T21:42:00.097Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 addTrack +29ms
2024-11-18T21:42:08.315Z goOnline called
2024-11-18T21:42:11.793Z handleOffer calleeId: 1657
2024-11-18T21:42:11.812Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setRemoteDescription +12s
2024-11-18T21:42:11.823Z icecandidate handling. Candidate: 
{"candidate":"candidate:2318461543 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.64 46558 typ host 
generation 0 ufrag ZMYl network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}
2024-11-18T21:42:11.829Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 addIceCandidate +17ms
2024-11-18T21:42:11.851Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 ontrack +23ms
2024-11-18T21:42:11.876Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setRemoteDescription OK +25ms
2024-11-18T21:42:11.884Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 createAnswer +7ms
2024-11-18T21:42:11.907Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setLocalDescription +23ms
2024-11-18T21:42:11.981Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setLocalDescription OK +75ms
2024-11-18T21:42:12.022Z icecandidate event: {"isTrusted":false,"candidate": 
{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.71 57511 typ host 
generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 4 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}. 
to calleeId=1657
2024-11-18T21:42:12.024Z icecandidate sent from callerId 3631 to calleeId 1657
2024-11-18T21:42:12.025Z icecandidate event: {"isTrusted":false,"candidate": 
{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.100.71 40459 typ host 
generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 3 network-cost 
900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}. to calleeId=1657
2024-11-18T21:42:12.028Z icecandidate sent from callerId 3631 to calleeId 1657

ANDROID 2 (Click 'Online' button second)
Running "MyAppChat" with {"rootTag":91}
Caller ID: 1657
2024-11-18T21:41:59.100Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 ctor +0ms
2024-11-18T21:41:59.270Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 addTrack +171ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.039Z goOnline called
2024-11-18T21:42:10.085Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 createOffer +11s
2024-11-18T21:42:10.097Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 createOffer OK +12ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.101Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setLocalDescription +4ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.124Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setLocalDescription OK +23ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.132Z icecandidate event: {"isTrusted":false,"candidate": 
{"candidate":"candidate:2318461543 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.64 46558 typ host 
generation 0 ufrag ZMYl network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}. 
to calleeId=3631
2024-11-18T21:42:10.134Z icecandidate sent from callerId 1657 to calleeId 3631
2024-11-18T21:42:10.589Z handleAnswer calleeId: 3631
2024-11-18T21:42:10.603Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setRemoteDescription +479ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.611Z icecandidate handling. Candidate: 
{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.71 57511 typ host 
generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 4 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}
2024-11-18T21:42:10.615Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 addIceCandidate +12ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.619Z icecandidate handling. Candidate: 
{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.100.71 40459 typ host 
generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 3 network-cost 900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}
2024-11-18T21:42:10.621Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 addIceCandidate +5ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.690Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 ontrack +70ms
2024-11-18T21:42:10.709Z rn-webrtc:pc:DEBUG 0 setRemoteDescription OK +19ms

Funny moment when I implemented this code earlier it was working and I hear my voice on another device. But then I decided to refactor my code and got stuck with this issue. Please have a look and suggest what wrong here. Why connection state is not changing in connected?
UPD. Logs from server:
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"connection","data":{"callerId":3631}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"connection","data":{"callerId":1657}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"online","data":{"callerId":3631}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"online","data":{"callerId":1657}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Send message to 1657: {"type":"candidate","calleeId":3631}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"offer","data":{"callerId":1657,"calleeId":3631,"description":{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4927643645049629581 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 102 0 8 13 110 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:ZMYl\r\na=ice-pwd:pN/XDsiBB3j+PSMGXvnCfJnc\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 03:F1:EC:E1:7B:B7:EE:B6:D1:49:C2:1C:8E:D0:66:32:86:8A:24:01:3D:51:3E:E9:04:F8:07:03:31:94:50:9E\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:- 0617d0de-159e-41c9-a5cf-4a93688af3c4\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:63 111/111\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1347046335 cname:7sEwid6xMN/ly4YI\r\na=ssrc:1347046335 msid:- 0617d0de-159e-41c9-a5cf-4a93688af3c4\r\n","type":"offer"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Send message to 3631: {"type":"offer","data":{"callerId":1657,"calleeId":3631,"description":{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4927643645049629581 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 102 0 8 13 110 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:ZMYl\r\na=ice-pwd:pN/XDsiBB3j+PSMGXvnCfJnc\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 03:F1:EC:E1:7B:B7:EE:B6:D1:49:C2:1C:8E:D0:66:32:86:8A:24:01:3D:51:3E:E9:04:F8:07:03:31:94:50:9E\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:- 0617d0de-159e-41c9-a5cf-4a93688af3c4\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:63 111/111\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1347046335 cname:7sEwid6xMN/ly4YI\r\na=ssrc:1347046335 msid:- 0617d0de-159e-41c9-a5cf-4a93688af3c4\r\n","type":"offer"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"icecandidate","data":{"calleeId":3631,"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2318461543 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.64 46558 typ host generation 0 ufrag ZMYl network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Send message to 3631: {"type":"icecandidate","data":{"calleeId":3631,"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2318461543 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.64 46558 typ host generation 0 ufrag ZMYl network-id 3 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"answer","data":{"callerId":3631,"calleeId":1657,"description":{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4803624590943004441 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 102 0 8 13 110 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:xxBl\r\na=ice-pwd:aVoQKA9A88gZENEOPgl/D4gA\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AC:FD:3F:CF:B8:00:5C:8C:37:1D:56:E7:9C:81:DC:96:2D:3C:3A:AB:8B:C3:AB:B2:0C:54:C6:B6:B3:0F:A4:C8\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:- c5e07f76-616a-4846-b751-4e2184b6db1b\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:63 111/111\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1877856903 cname:QuAoQveYXlBcJn/x\r\n"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Send message to 1657: {"type":"answer","data":{"callerId":3631,"calleeId":1657,"description":{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4803624590943004441 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 102 0 8 13 110 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:xxBl\r\na=ice-pwd:aVoQKA9A88gZENEOPgl/D4gA\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AC:FD:3F:CF:B8:00:5C:8C:37:1D:56:E7:9C:81:DC:96:2D:3C:3A:AB:8B:C3:AB:B2:0C:54:C6:B6:B3:0F:A4:C8\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:- c5e07f76-616a-4846-b751-4e2184b6db1b\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:63 111/111\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1877856903 cname:QuAoQveYXlBcJn/x\r\n"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"icecandidate","data":{"calleeId":1657,"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.71 57511 typ host generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 4 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Send message to 1657: {"type":"icecandidate","data":{"calleeId":1657,"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.100.71 57511 typ host generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 4 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Received message: {"type":"icecandidate","data":{"calleeId":1657,"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.100.71 40459 typ host generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 3 network-cost 900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}}
info: WebSocketServer.Controllers.WebSocketController[0]
      Send message to 1657: {"type":"icecandidate","data":{"calleeId":1657,"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1009425949 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.100.71 40459 typ host generation 0 ufrag xxBl network-id 3 network-cost 900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"0"}}} 

